# Как отсортировать объекты полученные из JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, сортировка

Как отсортировать массив объектов `data`, полученные из JSON.

**get-products.js**

```js
var data = [{
  "id": "0",
  "name": "stul"
}, {
  "id": "1",
  "name": "stol"
}, {
  "id": "4",
  "name": "json"
}]



  var productData;
  productData = data;
  
  $.each(productData, function(i, prod) {
    $('#products_section').append("<div>" + prod.id + "</div><div>" + prod.name + "</div>");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="products_section"></div>
```

как можно отсортировать их по `id` от большего к меньшему допустим, или по имени ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете отсортировать массив используя JavaScript [`sort()` функция](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

> Метод `sort()` сортирует элементы массива на месте и возвращает отсортированный массив.  По умолчанию используется возрастающий порядок сортировки, основанный на преобразовании элементов в строки и последующем сравнении их последовательностей значений кодовых единиц UTF-16.
>
> Сложность сортировки во времени и пространстве не может быть гарантирована, поскольку она зависит от реализации.

---

Для сортировки объектов массива надо использовать функцию сравнения.

> arr.sort ([compareFunction])
>
> **Параметры:**
>
> - `compareFunction` Optional Задает функцию, определяющую порядок сортировки.  Если не указано, элементы массива преобразуются в строки, а затем сортируются в соответствии со значением кодовой точки Unicode каждого символа.
>
>   - `FirstEl` - первый элемент для сравнения.
>   - `SecondEl` - второй элемент для сравнения.
>
> **Возвращаемое значение:**
>
> Отсортированный массив.  Обратите внимание, что массив сортируется на месте, а копии не создаются.

---